# How to convert this date based function into Moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I've already used Moment.js in my web app for other functions in the same component. Does it make sense to convert this function into Moment.js as well?

```
var t = new Date().getHours();

if (t < 10) {
    document.write("Have a good morning!");
} else if (t < 20) {
    document.write("Have a good day!");
} else {
    document.write("Have a good night!");
}
```

If yes then how can be it converted? How will it look like with Moment.js?

For completeness here is the other moment usage

```js
  let currentDay = moment.unix(weather.list[0].dt).get('date');
  let itemDay = moment.unix(item.dt).get('date'), 
  formattedDate(value) {
    return moment.unix(value.dt).format('dddd, D MMM');
  },
  formattedTime(value) {
    return moment.unix(value.dt).format('hh:mm a');
  },
```

Comment: Have you taken even a brief look at the Moment documentation?

Comment: Try `moment().hours()`

Comment: Yes, it's a bit confusing. As I said in the same component for other functions were already used.

Comment: No it does not make any sense to use moment here (and in many other places)

Comment: @mplungjan the reason that I asked was that other functions in the same component were already using Moment.

Comment: Perhaps we can translate your other functions to Vanilla JS?

Comment: I will share them now.

Comment: @mplungjan here are those lines:

 let currentDay = moment.unix(weather.list[0].dt).get('date');

let itemDay = moment.unix(item.dt).get('date')

 formattedDate (value) {
        return moment.unix(value.dt).format('dddd, D MMM');
      },

      formattedTime (value) {
        return moment.unix(value.dt).format('hh:mm a');
      },

Comment: PS: Be very careful not to use document.write after the page has loaded or the page will be wiped. I updated your question with the comment you made

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @mplungjan so how can be it converted? I mean Moment into Vanilla?

Comment: I do not have time to look at the documentation to see what dddd, D MMM does. But likely a version of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString will be enough

Comment: @mplungjan dddd is Monday - Sunday  value, MMMM is April, May...,  D is 1 - 31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Vanilla instead of moment

```js
const formattedTime = milli => new Date(milli).toLocaleString('en-GB', {
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
  hour12: true
});

const formattedDate = milli => new Date(milli).toLocaleString('en-GB', {
  weekday: "long",
  day: "numeric",
  month: "long"
});

const hello = milli => {
  const hour = new Date(milli).getHours();
  let text = "Have a good "
  switch (hour) {
    case hour <  6 : text += "night";   break; 
    case hour < 12 : text += "morning"; break; 
    case hour < 17 : text += "day";     break; 
    default        : text += "night";   break; 
  }
  return text;
}
console.log(formattedDate(1588362626178))
console.log(formattedTime(1588362626178))
console.log(hello(1588362626178))
```

This is my first class by the way

```js
class dateFormatter {
  constructor(millis) {
    this.value = "";
    this.date = new Date(millis);
  }
  formattedTime() {
    this.value = this.date.toLocaleString('en-GB', {
      hour: 'numeric',
      minute: 'numeric',
      hour12: true
    })
    return this;
  }
  formattedDate() {
    this.value = this.date.toLocaleString('en-GB', {
      weekday: "long",
      day: "numeric",
      month: "long"
    })
    return this
  }
  hello() {
    const hour = this.date.getHours();
    let text = "Have a good "
    switch (hour) {
      case hour < 6:
        text += "night";
        break;
      case hour < 12:
        text += "morning";
        break;
      case hour < 17:
        text += "day";
        break;
      default:
        text += "night";
        break;
    }
    this.value = text;
    return this;
  }
}
const df = new dateFormatter(1588362626178);
console.log(df.formattedDate().value)
console.log(df.formattedTime().value)
console.log(df.hello().value)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary but if you don't want to mix things, want consistency in your code then you should choose only one (Date or moment).

You can use moment.js like this

```
const currentDate =  moment();
const hours = currentDate.hours();

if (hours < 10) {
    document.write("Have a good morning!");
} else if (hours < 20) {
    document.write("Have a good day!");
} else {
    document.write("Have a good night!");
}
```